# Azure AzCopy command fail to copy csv files to Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake-gen2, azcopy

I am using this [Tutorial: Migrate on-premises data to cloud storage with AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-migrate-on-premises-data?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&tabs=windows) from Azure team to copy `csv` files from my local machine to an `Azure Blob Storage`. I followed the prerequisites and other requirements but I get the following error whether I copy the entire folder or an individual file.

**Question**: What could be a cause of the error and how can we resolve it?

**Remarks**: The folder has 4 files and each file is about 1GB of size.

**Error when copying a single file**:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> azcopy copy "C:\Junk1\MyFileName.csv" "https://myDataLakeStorageName.dfs.core.windows.net/myContainerName" --recursive=true
INFO: Scanning...
INFO: Authenticating to destination using Azure AD
INFO: Any empty folders will be processed, because source and destination both support folders

Job 9eea819a-e3f7-2a4c-4929-d382cc13f5b6 has started
Log file is located at: C:\Users\myusername\.azcopy\9eea819a-e3f7-2a4c-4929-d382cc13f5b6.log

0.0 %, 0 Done, 0 Failed, 1 Pending, 0 Skipped, 1 Total,


Job 9eea819a-e3f7-2a4c-4929-d382cc13f5b6 summary
Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.0334
Number of File Transfers: 1
Number of Folder Property Transfers: 0
Total Number of Transfers: 1
Number of Transfers Completed: 0
Number of Transfers Failed: 1
Number of Transfers Skipped: 0
TotalBytesTransferred: 0
Final Job Status: Failed
```

**Error when copying the entire folder**:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> azcopy copy "C:\Junk1\" "https://myDataLakeStorageName.dfs.core.windows.net/myContainerName" --recursive=true
INFO: Scanning...
INFO: Authenticating to destination using Azure AD
INFO: Any empty folders will be processed, because source and destination both support folders

Job 146c0764-b51d-eb40-6077-9fd70591baf0 has started
Log file is located at: C:\Users\myusername\.azcopy\146c0764-b51d-eb40-6077-9fd70591baf0.log

0.0 %, 0 Done, 0 Failed, 5 Pending, 0 Skipped, 5 Total,


Job 146c0764-b51d-eb40-6077-9fd70591baf0 summary
Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.0335
Number of File Transfers: 4
Number of Folder Property Transfers: 1
Total Number of Transfers: 5
Number of Transfers Completed: 0
Number of Transfers Failed: 5
Number of Transfers Skipped: 0
TotalBytesTransferred: 0
Final Job Status: Failed

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

**UPDATE**

Log file exceeds the size limit of a `Stack Overflow` post. But, per a request from user `@GauravMantri`, I'm attaching the link to the log file here: [AzCopy_Error_Log](https://ufile.io/w2ij0mhz). NOTE: This link will expire after 30 days from today November 21, 2021.

Comment: I am wondering if the log file contains any error details. Can you check that and share them in your question?

Comment: @GauravMantri Thank you for trying to help. I have added an **UPDATE** section to my post.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the error log. Looking at it, your uploads are failing with 401 error code. That is most likely coming because of insufficient permissions. Have you assigned `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role to your user account as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-migrate-on-premises-data?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fblobs%2Ftoc.json&tabs=windows#authenticate-with-azure-ad)?

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes, my `AAD` user account is a member of `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role, and I can upload the exact same file(s) manually - via Azure Portal - to the same `ADLSGen2` storage from my same personal laptop. But since each file is about `1GB` it's taking 15-20 minutes to load. I'm trying `AzCopy` to speed up the uploading process.

Comment: That’s weird! Instead of using Azure AD credentials, can you try using storage account key to upload using azcopy?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested in my environment.

I tried to copy files from local to storage using azcopy.

I have contributor access to the subscription. I created a data lake gen 2 storage account.

I can upload the blob files to the storage account using Azure portal.

I used AAD authentication to login to AzCopy

Now I used the below command to copy local files to Azure Storage account

```
azcopy copy "C:\Junk1\MyFileName.csv" "https://myDataLakeStorageName.dfs.core.windows.net/myContainerName/" --recursive=true
```

But received the below error:

**RESPONSE Status: 403 This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.**

[image]

I used the SAS token to authenticate the storage account and I am able to upload the files to Azure Storage account from my local

I used the below command:

```
azcopy copy "C:\Junk1\MyFileName.csv" "https://myDataLakeStorageName.dfs.core.windows.net/myContainerName/?sas-token" --recursive=true
```

[image]